# CustomArrayAdapter doesn't refresh after filter text has been removed

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-filter

Hey guys I've implemented my own ArrayAdapter because I have two textviews in the single ListView item. 
While the filtering works fine(it shows the correct items), when I delete the text that I have typed to filter the items the ListView doesn't go to its initial state(it doesn't display all items), instead it just leaves the filtered list unchanged.
Here is my filter implementation:

```
private class NightFilter extends Filter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        items = (ArrayList<NightOut>) results.values;
        clear();
        int count = items.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NightOut pkmn = (NightOut) items.get(i);
            add(pkmn);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            ArrayList<NightOut> list = new ArrayList<NightOut>(nightsOut);
            result.values = list;
            result.count = list.size();
        } else {
            final ArrayList<NightOut> list = new ArrayList<NightOut>(nightsOut);
            final ArrayList<NightOut> nlist = new ArrayList<NightOut>();
            int count = list.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final NightOut nightOut = list.get(i);
                final String value = nightOut.getAddress().toLowerCase();

                if (value.contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    nlist.add(nightOut);
                }
            }
            result.values = nlist;
            result.count = nlist.size();
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Both nightsOut and items contain the objects that i want to filter through(I assign those in the constructor). My custom adapter class extends ArrayAdapter if that's of any help.

Edit:

Added code for constructor and text filtering

```
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<NightOut> nightsOut) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, nightsOut);
    this.context = context;
    this.nightsOut = nightsOut;
    this.items = nightsOut;
}
```

Search method

```
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            ViewPlacesActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Cheers Kyle

Comment: where is your search method code?

Comment: What do you mean? I do the filtering in performFiltering method.  The search is pretty simple I have added a listener to edittext and ontextchanged method I perform filter like : Activity.this.adapter.getFilter.filter(cs)

Comment: The query text entered by your search / editText view.

Comment: Like I said ontextchanged i call something like  Activity.this.adapter.getFilter.filter(cs), cs is an entered charsequence

Comment: dont say, show it. maybe you're doing something wrong there..

Comment: Can you show the code to your custom `ArrayAdapter` constructor where you are assigning `items`, `nightsOut`, and calling the super constructor?

Comment: Sure @GeorgeMulligan ee revised question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are using `nightsOut` as the source list for your `ArrayAdapter` and also the source list for the filter is what is causing the problem.

In the `publishResults()` method you have a call to `clear()` which removes all elements from the `nightsOut` list inside `ArrayAdapter` since that is the list it references. You then readd only the filtered data.

Then the next time call `performFiltering()` you are using `nightsOut` as the source list again which only includes the filtered items.

What you want to do instead is keep a reference to your original items. You don't really need `items` the way it is currently used so I would rename that to `originalItems` and do the following:

```
public CustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<NightOut> nightsOut) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, nightsOut);
    this.context = context;
    this.nightsOut = nightsOut;
    originalItems = new ArrayList<>(nightsOut); // create a copy of nightsOut.
}
```

And then the filter

```
private class NightFilter extends Filter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayList<NightOut> tempList = (ArrayList<NightOut>) results.values;
        clear();
        addAll(tempList);
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            result.values = originalItems;
            result.count = originalItems.size();
        } else {
            final ArrayList<NightOut> nlist = new ArrayList<NightOut>();
            String lowerConstraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            // loop through originalItems which always contains all items
            for(NightOut nightOut : originalItems) {
                final String value = nightOut.getAddress().toLowerCase();
                if (value.contains(lowerConstraint)) {
                    nlist.add(nightOut);
                }
            }

            result.values = nlist;
            result.count = nlist.size();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I would let you marry my daughter if only I had one